# How to restrict Google Tag Manager click events to fire only when in a specific area of the page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager to track click events.

These events are contained within a certain section of the site - within a div `class="splash-slide-content"`

This div is not the parent div, from inspect element it looks like the grand parent.

What would be the best method of restricting the firing of this event? I'd like to create a new macro along the lines of something like: New macro "ancestor element" > ancestor class contains "splash-slide-content".

Then I could create a rule that says only fire if ancestor class contains "some string" (in this case "splash-slide-content")

Put another way, is there a way to specify "only fire this tag if it has an ancestor with class "splash-slide-content"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although an old question, in case someone is looking for the answer:
[image: Generic Click Trigger for elements with ancestor with a specific class]

Simply replace the `div` with the clicked element of choice (`span`,`p`,`li`,etc.).